# Handle HEAD request method using gunicorn and django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

Is there a way to force gunicorn to pass the handling of "HEAD" request method to a drf application?

Currently, I have a view which looks similar to the code below :-

```py
@api_view(["POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH", "HEAD"])
@renderer_classes([ProxyRender])
def my_proxy_view(request, path=""):

    return proxy_dispatch(
        urljoin(settings.PROXY["ENDPOINT"], path),
        request,
    )
```

However, when sending a "HEAD" request to the endpoint it seems like gunicorn or Django is the one handling the response, not my view as invoking my view should yield a head result of the service behind.

```
$ curl -I "http://localhost:8000/proxy/some-endpoint"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn
Date: Sat, 20 Aug 2022 15:29:57 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 106
Vary: Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```

Comment: The **HEAD** method is used to ask only for information about a document, not for the document itself. So if you want to invoke your view then use **GET**

Comment: Are you trying to pass the HEAD request through to a different service?

Comment: @jordanm exactly

Comment: If you have nginx in front of gunicorn, I would just configure the proxy there.

Comment: @jordanm The django application handles initial authentication to several services which is why I'm using it as a web proxy